# Read XML file list data in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a folder full of xml files all in the same format but with different and ever changing file names

I am wondering if there is a way where I can get Visual Basic to just go through all files available so as I can extract the data from all?

Comment: You sure can: Foreach file in folder { do something }. If you want a more detailed answer you need to post some more details yourself, for example what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim di As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Some Directory")
    Dim xmlFiles As System.IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.xml")
    For Each xmlFile As System.IO.FileInfo In xmlFiles
        ' do some data processing here
    Next
```